# Problem with opening google chrome

Tags: 16.04, google-chrome

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on virtual box with windows 10 host. When I open chrome only black screen appeared. Anyone know how can I get rid of this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling hardware acceleration in Chrome. In Chrome go to Settings, click Show Advanced Settings, Scroll down to the System section and uncheck Use hardware acceleration when available. This has caused it to be all black for me in the past when the video drivers have not been able to do the job.